# PHP - Como fazer com que o left join com mais de um registro nas demais tabelas não retorne valores repetidos nas colunas?

Tags: php, mysql, query, join

Estou precisando realizar um query SQL no PHP, onde preciso criar uma tabela a partir de outras 9 tabelas, juntando todas as colunas com um LEFT JOIN, e com o campo 'Cliente' como chave entre as tabelas. Porém, em cada tabela há mais de um registro da mesma chave, ou seja, mais de uma linha com o mesmo número de 'Cliente', e com isso a consulta está me retornando valores repetidos, mudando apenas os valores das colunas que são de dados diferentes. 
Eu gostaria que esses valores repetidos das colunas, apenas aparecesse um só vez, e nos demais, me retornasse com NULL. Vou colocar logo abaixo uma imagem mostrando como está sendo me retornado os valores.
Alguém faz ideia de como resolver isso? 
Agradeço imensamente desde já!

Segue o código da query:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM completo_sem_saldo 
 LEFT JOIN posicao_contabil ON (completo_sem_saldo.Cliente = posicao_contabil.Cliente) 
 LEFT JOIN saldo_analitico ON (completo_sem_saldo.Cliente = saldo_analitico.Cliente) 
 LEFT JOIN titulos_em_ser ON (completo_sem_saldo.Cliente = titulos_em_ser.Cliente
```

**COMO ESTA RETORNANDO:**
[image: valores retornados]

**COMO QUERO QUE RETORNE:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CÓDIGO COMPLETO DA TABELA:**

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM completo_sem_saldo as a LEFT JOIN posicao_contabil as b ON (a.Cliente = b.Cliente_Posicao) LEFT JOIN saldo_analitico as c ON (a.Cliente = c.Cliente_Saldo_Analitico) LEFT JOIN titulos_em_ser as d ON (a.Cliente = d.Cliente_Titulos_Em_Ser) ) as e");

$num = mysqli_num_rows($query1);
$resul1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
$arquivo = 'exemplo.xls';
$tabela = '<table border="1">';
$tabela .= '<tr>';
$tabela .= '<td colspan="2">Formulario</tr>';
$tabela .= '</tr>';
$tabela .='<tr>';
$tabela .='<td><b>Nome</b></td>';
$tabela .='<td><b>Sld_dev_ctbl</b></td>';
$tabela .= '<td><b>Saldo</b></td>';
$tabela .='<td><b>Vlr_atual</b></td>';
$tabela .='</tr>';

while($resul1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)) {

$nome = $resul1['Nome'];
$sld_dev_ctbl = $resul1['Sld_dev_ctbl'];
$saldo = $resul1['Saldo'];
$vlr_atual = $resul1['Vlr_atual'];

$tabela .= '<tr>';
$tabela .= '<td>'.$nome.'</td>';
$tabela .= '<td>'.$sld_dev_ctbl.'</td>';
$tabela .= '<td>'.$saldo.'</td>';
$tabela .= '<td>'.$vlr_atual.'</td>';
$tabela .= '</tr>';
}
$tabela .= '</table>';
```

Comment: Atualizei com o código na descrição.

Comment: Ja testou um GROUP BY ?

Comment: Na verdade já, mas nem funfou. O que realmente preciso é que a join me retorne apenas os valores encontrados nas tabelas, e não repita os demais valores anteriores. :/

Comment: as colunas `Sld_dev_ctbl` e `Saldo` têm sempre o mesmo valor? Aparecendo a soma do `Vlr_atual` para determinado cliente resolve?

Comment: Na verdade apenas a coluna 'Saldo' sempre irá ter o mesmo valor para um cliente. As colunas 'Sld_dev_ctbl' e 'Vlr_atual' sempre irão ter valores diferentes, quando aparecem mais de um vez pra um cliente.

Comment: Por que vc não faz esse tratamento na aplicação ao invés de tratar por sql? Eu desconheço outra maneira a não ser aplicar `pivot`... Em linhas curtas, acho que seu select está certo.. você tem que tratar na aplicação o que você quer.

Comment: Posta uma imagem do que você quer que retorne e o que está retornando. Não consegui entender o quer exatamente. :(  Se for para anular as repetições você tem que ver o que está igual, humanamente. Seria somente adicionar isto: `GROUP BY Nome`

Comment: Acabei de colocar outra imagem mostrando como realmente quero que fique o resultado da query. Pode perceber que os valores repetidos na primeira imagem, não se repetem na segunda, só aparecem uma única vez.

Comment: tu tentou usar "select distinct ..."?

Comment: Na verdade, o DISTINCT faz com que retorne os valores que são duplicados, e não é bem isso que preciso. Preciso que ele pegue os valores duplicados, exclua (NULL), e só deixe apenas o primeiro registro.

Comment: É isso que você quer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286417/mysql-join-return-null-for-duplicate-results-in-left-table

Answer (score 0):

Isso não é um problema de SQL, no momento em que você faz um join você está gerando um ["Produto Cartesiano"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produto_cartesiano).

O que posso te sugerir é durante o processamento dos dados, exibir apenas as informações que você não quer que repita na primeira ocasião do ID do cliente.

Não sei como está o seu código, mas vai um exemplo genérico:

```
<?php
$rows = array();

$row['cliente_id'] = 1;
$row['nome'] = 'fulano';
$row['saldo'] = 10;
$row['valor'] = 1;
$rows[] = $row; 

$row['cliente_id'] = 1;
$row['nome'] = 'fulano';
$row['saldo'] = 10;
$row['valor'] = 2;
$rows[] = $row; 

$row['cliente_id'] = 1;
$row['nome'] = 'fulano';
$row['saldo'] = 10;
$row['valor'] = 3;
$rows[] = $row; 

$row['cliente_id'] = 2;
$row['nome'] = 'fulano';
$row['saldo'] = 10;
$row['valor'] = 1;
$rows[] = $row; 

$row['cliente_id'] = 2;
$row['nome'] = 'fulano';
$row['saldo'] = 10;
$row['valor'] = 2;
$rows[] = $row; 

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>ID</th>";
echo "<th>Nome</th>";
echo "<th>Saldo</th>";
echo "<th>Valor</th>";
echo "</tr>";

$last_id = null;
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo $last_id != $row['cliente_id'] ? "<td>$row[cliente_id]</td>" : "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>$row[nome]</td>";
    echo $last_id != $row['cliente_id'] ? "<td>$row[saldo]</td>" : "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>$row[valor]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $last_id = $row['cliente_id'];
}
echo "</table>";
```

Se tu postar o teu código, como está montando a tabela podemos ajudar no caso real.

Comment: Acabei de atualizar na descrição o código completo. Se poder me ajudar brother, ficarei imensamente grato. Dá uma olhadinha no código.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o comande `DISTINCT` após o operador `SELECT` e chamar o campo que você não quer que se repita, geralmente você faz isso no ID, assim ele não vai combinar todas entradas do plano cartesiano.

[Exemplo em W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) (Inglês)
[Exemplo em MySQL Tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx) (Inglẽs)